# Random background image for each class instance

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a sass function which returns a random url from a given set of urls as follows:

```
@function randomUrl(){
    $images: (
    "/images/watermarks/area-watermark.png",
    "/images/watermarks/bar-watermark.png",
    "/images/watermarks/line-watermark.png",   
     $img: nth($images, random(length($images)));     
     @return $img;
}
```

and i am assigning it to a class as follows:

```
.myClass{
 background-image: url(randomUrl());
}
```

What i want now is to get a random image **FOR EACH** class instance, i.e,  if i have 10 divs with class "myClass" in my HTML, i want the background images of each div to be different. My approach till now just gives me one random image which appears in all the divs everytime i compile.

Answer (score 0):

The `random()` function does exactly what it sounds like:  it generates a random number between 2 specified numbers.  There is no guarantee that the numbers will be different each time the function is called because that's not how random works.

What you need is a way to *shuffle* your list, but there is no such function to do that in the Sass standard library.  There are a couple of 3rd party libraries that do:

- https://github.com/at-import/SassyLists (sl-shuffle)
- https://github.com/mknadler/randomize.scss (shuffle)

The implementation in both libraries is nearly identical (this one was lifted from randomize.scss):

```
@function shuffle($list) { 
  $list-length: length($list);

  @while($list-length > 0) {
    $rand: random($list-length);
    $temp: nth($list, $rand);
    $list: set-nth($list, $rand, nth($list, $list-length));
    $list: set-nth($list, $list-length, $temp);
    $list-length: $list-length - 1;
  }

  @return $list;
}
```

If you're intentionally avoiding iterating over a list, you could use it like this:

```
@import "SassyLists";

$last-pos: 0;
$images: sl-shuffle(
  "/images/watermarks/area-watermark.png"
  "/images/watermarks/bar-watermark.png"
  "/images/watermarks/line-watermark.png");

@function randomUrl(){
  $last-pos: if($last-pos == length($images), 1, $last-pos + 1) !global;
  @return nth($images, $last-pos);
}

.myClass {
  background-image: url(randomUrl());
}

.myClass {
  background-image: url(randomUrl());
}

.myClass {
  background-image: url(randomUrl());
}
```

Output:

```
.myClass {
  background-image: url("/images/watermarks/line-watermark.png");
}

.myClass {
  background-image: url("/images/watermarks/area-watermark.png");
}

.myClass {
  background-image: url("/images/watermarks/bar-watermark.png");
}
```

Though I recommend just using iteration instead and cut out the use of the function all together:

```
@import "SassyLists";

$images: sl-shuffle(
  "/images/watermarks/area-watermark.png"
  "/images/watermarks/bar-watermark.png"
  "/images/watermarks/line-watermark.png");

@for $i from 1 through length($images) {
  .myClass-#{$i} {
    background-image: url(nth($images, $i));
  }
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/d0c65d02be52aa31f836